# use realm instance across different activities which using predefined realm database

Tags: android, realm

I add predefined realm database to my app successufully and get the data

```
copyBundledRealmFile(this.getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.test), 
"test");

    RealmConfiguration config1 = new RealmConfiguration.Builder(this)
            .name("test")
            .schemaVersion(1)
            .migration(new Migration())
            .build();
    realm = Realm.getInstance(config1);
realm.close();

private String copyBundledRealmFile(InputStream inputStream, String outFileName) {
    try {
        File file = new File(this.getFilesDir(), outFileName);
        FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(file);
        byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
        int bytesRead;
        while ((bytesRead = inputStream.read(buf)) > 0) {
            outputStream.write(buf, 0, bytesRead);
        }
        outputStream.close();
        return file.getAbsolutePath();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

the problem how to get instance of the realm when I try using

```
       realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
```

give me empty data 
how can get instance across the app

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To be able to *get* a default, you have to *set* a default:

```
RealmConfiguration config1 = new RealmConfiguration.Builder(this)
        .name("test")
        .schemaVersion(1)
        .migration(new Migration())
        .build();

Realm.setDefaultConfiguration(config1); // <-- here
```

Now you can get it with

```
Realm.getDefaultInstance();
```

Comment: thanks a lot for your reply  do I need  set Realm.setDefaultConfiguration(config1); every time I open the app or can I add it once because it take a long time

Comment: Just once in your `extends Application` class